Would a fulltext index across multiple columns be better in this case?
Currently, the search query that I'm using for searching my forum looks like this (this particular search was for the term "6.18") (this is just part of the where clause that deals with searching:
(
    INSTR(LOWER(author), "6.18")
 OR INSTR(LOWER(subject), "6.18")
 OR id IN (SELECT forum_text_id
             FROM `forum_text`
            WHERE MATCH(text) AGAINST("6.18")
              AND moderated IS NOT NULL)
 OR INSTR(LOWER(email), "6.18")
OR INSTR(LOWER(DATE(updated)), "6.18")
)

To optimise it I realise that, depending on the search query, I could cut out a few of those where clauses (eg there's no point searching the updated field - a date field - if there's anything but numbers and hyphens in the query term (I convert words like July to -07- beforehand)
But how about spreading the fulltext index across multiple fields and just having a single match/against clause? Would that be a better way of doing things than all those WHERE clauses?
eg create the index with something like this:
ALTER TABLE messages ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `messages-meta-information` (author, subject, email, updated);

So the search query might look like this:
(
    id IN (SELECT forum_text_id
             FROM `forum_text`
            WHERE MATCH(author, subject, email, updated) AGAINST("6.18")
 OR id IN (SELECT forum_text_id
             FROM `forum_text`
            WHERE MATCH(text) AGAINST("6.18")
              AND moderated IS NOT NULL)
)


Fulltext search will not yield exactly the same results as instr or like operator as it operates on words, not on substrings. There is no point using fulltext index on email and date columns as those do not contain words that could be indexed. You would have to check first if you are happy with fulltext search outputs, which only you can validate.

So with a fulltext index a search for the term "bcd" wouldn't find the word "abcde" ?

Hmmm, it would appear not. I could live with that though.

Correct. Mysql fulltext search cannot find a substring in the middle or at the end of a word.

How about adding multiple match/against clauses for multiple text fields that each have their own full text index - is that feasible?

Mysql can use only one FT index per table per query, so I would not suggest this approach.

One per table? So if you had two tables in one query (via a join), each with a FT index on them, could both FT indexes be utilised?

Yep, that's correct.
